# How can I trigger scripts (lock screen) when leaving a specific WiFi on OSX?

Tags: macos, automator, network

I dimly remember hearing about an OSX application that let you, for example, enable password lock when leaving the current WiFi, but I can't find it anymore. Does anyone know how it's called? Thanks!

Comment: Long shot...[MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/), or its "successor" [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/)?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you're actually looking for a setting in OS X:

**System Preferences → Network → Advanced**

[image]

Comment: Not exactly… this setting only prompts you with a password dialog when changing networks. What I'm actually looking for is a way to require a password to login only on the go while granting free access at home. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if this exists.

Typically when you walk out of/into a wifi network's range your mac will be turned off, which means nothing can run while you're crossing the boundary. Unlike iOS, there is no API on OS X for running code when you enter/exit a specific location even while the device is turned off. This is a feature that needs hardware support, and Macs don't have it.

Scripts executed by utilities like ControlPlane will not run until after you actually wake your mac up again, and by then it's too late to change the wake-from-sleep behaviour.

It might be possible with some deep hacks into the system, but I'd be surprised.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you may be thinking of Sidekick.app

http://oomphalot.com/sidekick/

Answer (score 1):

Months later, but I came across this post so thought I'd share my findings. [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com) is a free alternative to Sidekick, and does exactly what you're asking. By default, you can have your screensaver password enabled, and disable only when meeting certain criteria, such as joining a particular wifi network, identified by SSID or BSSID.